# Check value in rows with same FK

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the table below

```
ID  | PARCEL  | STATUS  | ORDER_ID
1     1         COMPLETE     1234
2     2         COMPLETE     1234
3     1         COMPLETE     9999 
4     2         PENDING      9999   
5     3         PENDING      9999
6     1         COMPLETE     1111
7     2         COMPLETE     1111
8     3         COMPLETE     1111   
9     1         COMPLETE     3333 
10    2         PENDING      3333
```

I need select the order_id with ALL PARCEL's having a COMPLETE status.

i am trying with select, but don't work

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE order_id NOT IN 
(SELECT order_id  FROM table WHERE status = 'COMPLETE');
```

the answer for the query is

```
ID  | PARCEL  | STATUS  | ORDER_ID
1     1         COMPLETE     1234
2     2         COMPLETE     1234
6     1         COMPLETE     1111
7     2         COMPLETE     1111
8     3         COMPLETE     1111
```

Comment: Any reason not to use `where status = 'complete'`?

Comment: Sorry, i edit the query and this is the correct. SELECT * FROM table WHERE order_id NOT IN 
(SELECT order_id  FROM table WHERE status = 'COMPLETE');

Comment: You want to only return order_ids that only have complete status in their record.  In other words, the "pending" status, must not exist for that order id. is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` clause, so it will skip any order_id that has status other than COMPLETE

```
   SELECT * FROM tableA A1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    ( SELECT 1 from tableA A2
      where A1.order_id= A2.order_id
      and A2.status <> 'COMPLETE'
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

select * from table_parcels where STATUS like 'COMPLETE';

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer its always better if it provides aditional value. In your case there is a previous answer with the exact same solution